# Relation between the b-function of a holonomic module and the b-function of its corresponding holonomic dual

Tags: d-modules

Let $D=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n, \partial_1, \ldots, \partial_n]$ be the Weyl algebra with $k$ a field of characteristic zero. 
Given a holonomic D-module $M$ we know that its holonomic dual $M^{'}=\text{Ext}_D^n(M, D)$ it is also holonomic.
Also we now both modules being holonomic have a well defined b-function.

My question: is there any relation relation between the b-functions of $M$  and $M^{'}$?

Thanks in advance!